# Script to run jupyter notebooks from remote server

Tags: ubuntu, jupyter-notebook

I have a server (Ubuntu server 16.04) that runs jupyter notebooks, and a local machine (Mac) where I use google-chrome to visualize these notebooks. To do so, I have to:

1. Run jupyter notebook in the server:

   jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=${remotePort}
2. Specify a SHH tunnel in my local machine:

   ssh -f ${username}@${serverIP} -L ${localPort}:localhost:${remotePort}

To automate this process, I've created the script jupyter.sh (described below), such that I only run on my local machine:

```
bash jupyter.sh -u myUserNameInServer
```

It works flawlessly. It's able to run the previous two steps plus it automatically open the jupyter page in my web-browser. Still, I would like to know if there is a better way to do this. I would greatly appreciate your comments.

Thanks in advance.

```
#######################################################################
## 1. SET VARIABLES TO STABLISH THE SSH CONNECTION
# Get username from command line: bash jupyter.sh -u username
while [[ $# -gt 1 ]]
do
key="$1"
case $key in
    -u|--username)
    username="$2"
    shift # past argument
    ;;
esac
shift # past argument or value
done
# Specificy other variables to stablish the ssh connection
localPort=8890
browser="Google Chrome"
serverIP=the_IP_of_the_server
#######################################################################
# 2. RUN JUPYTER IN REMOTE SERVER
out=$(ssh -T ${username}@${serverIP} <<HERE
    # Only run jupyter if it isn't already running
    if [ \$(ps -u ${username} | grep jupyter | wc -l) -eq 0 ]
    then
        # Create a folder called jupyter, and move into it
        if [ ! -d jupyter ]; then mkdir jupyter; fi
        cd jupyter
        # Create a script to run jupyter
        echo "jupyter notebook --no-browser --NotebookApp.token=${username}" > jupyter.sh 
        # Run jupyter in the background
        screen -S jupyter -d -m bash jupyter.sh
    fi
    # Output the remote port number. If there is more than 1, get the first one
    jupyter notebook list | grep localhost | awk '{split(\$0,a,"localhost:");split(a[2],b,"/"); print b[1]}' | head -n1
HERE
)

#######################################################################
# 3. SET SSH TUNNEL
# Pass the remote port to a variable in the local machine
remotePort=$(echo $out | awk '{print $NF}') 
# Start listening in local port 8890 if that port isn't already in use
# num equal 1 if port number is already in use, 0 otherwise
num=$(netstat -lnt | awk 'BEGIN{x=0} ($6 == "LISTEN" && $4 ~ "8890$"){x=1}END{print x}')
if [ $num -eq 0 ]
then
    ssh -f ${username}@${serverIP} -L ${localPort}:localhost:${remotePort} -N
fi
#
# Open jupyter in browser
open -a "${browser}" http://localhost:${localPort}/tree?token=${username} &
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "jupyter config file" wich is not activated by default so need to do this command fisrt (on your server):

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

Then in the generated "jupyter_notebook_config.py" in the "/.jupyter"  folder :
uncomment the line and change the value.

This way you can tweak configuation such as password instead of token, default directory , port and so on .. Do as you want it may be a proper way to do some of the "jupyter config" in your script then keep evertything else.