# Unable to open connection: Host does not exist

Tags: virtualenv, jupyter-notebook, putty, ssh-tunnel, plink

I have been to access Jupyter Notebook on remote server (on a gpu). I followed [this guide](https://coderwall.com/p/ohk6cg/remote-access-to-ipython-notebooks-via-ssh) but getting this error "Unable to open connection: Host does not exist" after running the following command:

```
 C::\WINDOWS\system32> plink ssh -N -L localhost:8888:localhost:8889 remote_user@remote_host
```

OS: Windows

Using plink to create ssh tunnel.

Any idea what's going wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

And again solved this problem by using this command:

```
plink -ssh -L 8888:localhost:8888 ml_test #ml_test is my putty session name, you can provide your username@remote-host
```

As mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43696291/script-to-run-jupyter-notebooks-from-remote-server).