# How to launch jupyter notebooks on server via ssh and run it on local browser?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, ssh, jupyter-notebook

I'm working on a project where the servers and Mysql data bases are inaccessible from my local machine unless I ssh to a remote using terminal. However, I find programming with Jupyter Notebooks the best environment for me. I really miss it as I find programming with just vim remotely via terminal a bit cumbersome. I was wondering if there was a way to launch Jupyter notebook from the server and have my local browser open it up- so I can code from my browser but it would be running from the terminal/remote-server via ssh- so that ways my code can actually connect to my database from my browser via the remote and I can use the interactiveness of a Jupyter notebook to speed up my development. Any ideas? remote is ubuntu and mine is a mac. Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43696291/1978759) for a method to do this

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple. You just need to install the jupyter notebook server on your remote machine and make it open to the web, protected by a password to avoid unintended use.

On the remote server, first install Jupyter:

```
pip3 install jupyter
```

Then follow this [guide](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html) to secure it with a password.

At last you can launch it with:

```
jupyter notebook --ip='*'
```

This tells Jupyter to make it available from any ip and not only from localhost.

Please **do protect it** with a password, otherwise very nasty things could happen to your server.